# Calling JS function automatically after image is loaded by java backing bean

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, xhtml

I need my `JS` resizing function to be called automatically after image is returned by java backing bean. This is `xhtml` part responsible for image loading. It is part of `dataGrid`.

```
<p:panel id="panel1" >
    <p:graphicImage id="image1" value="#{imageService.image}"  width="100%" height="100%">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{kprod.id}" />
    </p:graphicImage>
</p:panel>
```

This is **bean method**:

```
public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }
    else {
        String id = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
        return findImage(Long.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

After completing the rendering phase, it goes to else branch which returns actual image.

I have working `JS` function `resizeImage()`. I tested it by adding attribute `onclick="resizeImage()"` to `<p:graphicImage>` and then clicked on image and it resized correctly. What I need now is automatic calling of this function.
`<p:graphicImage>` doesnt have any attributes that I can use. I also tried `<p:ajax oncomplete="resizeImage()" />` to involve into `<p:graphicImage>` node but every time I use `ajax` this **error** is returned:

> Event attribute could not be determined: null

I also have one sub question. Actual image id in final `HTML` is `contentForm:kprods:7:image1` where number is variable according to order. Is there a way how to pass to `JS` id of the element as a parameter?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pure client side issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157657/ddg#39160299

Comment: I know it is client side.I wanted client to resize images not server.But my findings regarding to your comment.
When I use 
`$("image1").load(function() {
 console.log("test");
});`
my console prints nothing.
If I use `$("image1").load(resizeImage());` it always goes to resizeImage() function. But it goes there no matter what ID I use. If I use `$("whatever").load(resizeImage());` it goes to function too. But no image is resized. Seem like `$(this).height(h);` doesnt work because "this" not reffers to image. Same for width. And it is called just once, despite I have more images rendered.

Comment: uhhhhhhh.... Please learn basic jquery... `$("image1")` tries to find the HTML tag with `image1` as the tag!!! Use it like in the link `$("img")` or `$("#image1")` if you want to use the id

Comment: This prints nothing to console `$("img").load(function() { console.log("test"); });`
This neither `$("#image1").load(function() { console.log("test"); });`

This `$("foo").load(printTest());` prints text to console always no matter what is the ID. 
I dont understand why it behaves like this.

Comment: Are you sure that `$("img").load(function() ...` is executed before the images are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found solution. Basically all I needed was to run my function on **load** event. But primefaces element `<p:graphicImage>` doesnt have *onload* attribute.

So I added to my xhtml new namespace for passthrough attributes:

`xmlns:x="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`.

And added `x:onload` attribute to graphicImage element:

```
<p:panel id="panel1" >
    <p:graphicImage id="image1" value="#{imageService.image}" x:onload="resizeImage(this.id)" width="100%" height="100%">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{kprod.id}" />
    </p:graphicImage>
</p:panel>
```

Then I inspected final HTML and there was onload attribute with my function added to `<img>` element.